# Changing Censor Shapes in R (prodlim, survminer, cmprsk) with marktime

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I'm plotting a response curve, and want the censor to show as a X (or something different).

I've tried adding `censor.shape ="X"` and `pch = "X"` after marktime but it doesn't work. (in brackets after `marktime = TRUE`, in commas after, without `marktime`, without `TRUE`)

I have a strong suspicion that the error originates from me not knowing where to place the argument... so most of them are "Error: unexpected...". However I have also seen

```
Warning message: In SmartControl(call = list(...), keys = c("plot", "lines", "atrisk", : 
The following argument(s) are not smart and therefore ignored: censor.shape"
```

Can anyone provide some insight on where I'm going wrong? Many thanks.

```
    library(cmprsk)
    library(survminer)
    library(prodlim)

    ...

    # Cumulative incidence function
    CIF <- prodlim(Hist(Time_M, Group, cens.code=0)~1, MMR)

    # Plot cumulative incidence curve

    plot(CIF, type="cuminc",
    marktime = TRUE,
    lwd = 1.0,
    Axis1.at=seq(0,70,5), 
    axis2.las=2, 
    background.horizontal= FALSE,
    percent = FALSE, 
    confint = FALSE, 
    ylab = "Probability of response", 
    xlab= "Time in Months")
    title("Major Molecular Response for 2nd line only", adj = 0.5, line = 0.75)
```

Comment: `Error in terms.formula(x = formula, specials = specials, data = data) : 
  object 'MMR' not found`

Comment: @42- sorry, MMR was my data set, should I mention that in the question?

Comment: My point was that further efforts at debugging or investigators were futile without data!